# CSV - list index out of range

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I get this error reading CSV file (no headers, 3 columns, 2nd and 3rd strings):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python32\fantasy.py", line 72, in module>
some=row[1]
IndexError: list index out of range*
```

Here is part of the code below. It's stupidly simple stuff to be stuck on, but I'm just blank about how it isn't working. I'm new to coding, but have dealt with csv module before and never had problems with this part, and just made some test csv file in notepad to see if it will be read from the same code, and it does. I don't know.

```
import csv
##############some other code, working good and I believe not relevant to this problem
file=open(r"C:\Users\me\Desktop\file-2.csv","r")
reader=csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for row in reader:
    some=row[1]
```

Comment: print repr(row) just before the error. Open with `newline=''` if there could be embed newlines in a field

Comment: Sorry, Sebastian, but I find it difficult to interpret. Could you write integral code of it?

Comment: Anyway, I don't know if this is important, but I used shutil to make the same file that I'm trying to read.

Comment: Can you show us the file contents you are trying to read? One of the lines must be too short.

Comment: Well, first column is case number. - 1,Arsenal,Mannone 2,Arsenal,Jenkinson and so on

Comment: 1. Add line `print(repr(row))` before the `some=row[1]` line in your code, copy-paste the last thing that is printed before you see Traceback... 2. See [the very first code example in the docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv) on how to use `newline=''`

Comment: You may have a blank or too-short line in the file.  There could possibly be an extra newline character (blank line) at the end of the file.  Open the file in a text editor and look for a funny line.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: I had the same error (hence that I'm commenting here). After checking the code quite a few times, I found out that the error was not in the code, but that a comma was missing in the CSV. IMHO worth checking.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try checking for blank lines. Also, avoid using `file` as a variable name. `"r"` is the default mode with open.

```
import csv

with open(r"C:\Users\me\Desktop\file-2.csv") as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
     for row in reader:
        if row:
            some=row[1]
```

Comment: There is no `file` builtin in Python 3. Even in Python 2 `file` is an exception to the rule and could be used as a variable name (It is recommended to use `open()` instead of `file()` and it is too good name to ignore).

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have an empty line or something. By default each iteration of your for loop grabs a line of text from your csv file. That row of text ends with a newline character. So if you have a blank line then the reader reads it as something like this [].

Do this and you will see what I mean:

```
for row in reader:
    print(repr(row))
    some = row[1]
```

You will find that the last row that gets printed is not of length 2 or more.

There are a few things you can do to fix this:

1. Pass the file through some cleanup script to remove blank lines
2. change the recognized newline character when you call reader

Answer (score 6):

This question is old, but I ran into a slightly different solution to this problem so I will put it here for anyone else who might have this problem. My file was so large I could not see the end of it. At the end there was a row with only 2 things in it instead of the typical 5 of my file so when I tried to get the fourth column it was giving me this error. Here was my solution:

```
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 2:
            array.append(row[3])
```

Comment: Can you formt your answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer ! That `len()` is a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error before as well.  My issue was stupid and avoidable though.  I copied some code from another program and didn't change the delimiter (in my case from pipe to comma), so of course it was going beyond it's index looking for a pipe when one never existed.