# IndexError: list index out of range - CSV file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

There is an error in my code - `IndexError: list index out of range, at rates[row[0]] = row[1]`:

```
def change():
    # read file into dictionary
    with open('exchangeRate.csv', 'r') as in_file:
        echRdr = csv.reader(in_file)
        for row in echRdr:
            rates[row[0]] = row[1]
```

it is because there  are empty lines in my file due to editing and the easiest way to solve this is to make it skip these lines, how would i do that?

Comment: Have you tried printing `row`? Looks like it could provide some insight.

Comment: similar to comments above.  one of your rows has less than 2 entries.  you could skip such rows with `if len(row) > 1:`  but probably best to understand the fail case first

Comment: Note that if you're using Python 3, you should use `'r', newline='')`, not merely `'r'`, as explained in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Comment: the file does have line with nothing in them and that will stay this way due to editing, so it would be much easier to allow this here, how would that be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python CSV - list index out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039392/python-csv-list-index-out-of-range)

Comment: @MatthewTrevor i saw that earlier and i know the problem is blank lines, but i wish to keep them as it makes editing easier (so i dont have to change other parts of the code). So what is the bes way to bypass the blank lines?

Comment: @user3165683 Don't just read the question, [read the solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13046897/11265).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple condition in the for loop may solve the issue.

```
def change():
    # read file into dictionary
    with open('exchangeRate.csv', 'r') as in_file:
    echRdr = csv.reader(in_file)
    for row in echRdr:
        if len(row) <= 1:
            pass
        else:
            rates[row[0]] = row[1]
```