# getting first column CSV file Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Trying to get first column (names) into a list to show the user and is then updated with the changes to CSV file.
Using this code:

```
import csv
list = []
exRtFile = open ('exchangeRate.csv','r')
exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile)
while True:
    for column in exchReader:
        list.append(column and column[0])
        print(list)
        exRtFile.close
```

However, i get the underired output of:

```
['US Dollar']
['US Dollar', []]
['US Dollar', [], 'Japanese Yen']
['US Dollar', [], 'Japanese Yen', []]
['US Dollar', [], 'Japanese Yen', [], 'Euro']
['US Dollar', [], 'Japanese Yen', [], 'Euro', []]
['US Dollar', [], 'Japanese Yen', [], 'Euro', [], 'Pound Sterling']
['US Dollar', [], 'Japanese Yen', [], 'Euro', [], 'Pound Sterling', []]
['US Dollar', [], 'Japanese Yen', [], 'Euro', [], 'Pound Sterling', [], 'Japanese Yen']
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name; you are masking the built-in type.

Comment: Since `csv.reader` gives you rows, your `column` variable is confusingly named-- you're iterating over the rows, and want `row[0]`.  (PS: don't forget [`newline=''`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991406/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-csv-file#comment35112723_22991406)!)

Answer (score 3):

You are appending the empty `column` list every other row; test for the column *before* appending:

```
col = []
exRtFile = open ('exchangeRate.csv','r')
exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile)
for column in exchReader:
    if column:
        col.append(column[0])
```

Do *not* use an endless loop (`while True:`) in there.

Or using a list comprehension and the file as a context manager to close it automatically:

```
with open('exchangeRate.csv', newline='') as exRtFile:
    exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile)
    col = [c[0] for c in exchReader if c]
```

Note that I added the `newline=''` argument to the `open()` call; this is recommended for CSV files because they can use a mix of line endings between values and rows, which the `csv.reader()` will manage for you if you let it.