# I am trying to read a CSV file from python, here is my code

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to check a csv file for specific data and then have it print the whole row.

code:

```
import csv 
from datetime import *
Date = date.today()
strDate = str(Date)
File = (strDate + ".csv")
count = 1



with open(File, "r") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in csvreader:
        if row[0] == ("1"):
            print(row)
```

the file being read contains:

```
1,Test1,2015-10-19
2,Test2,2015-10-19
```

The error code:

```
>>> 
['1', 'Test1', '2015-10-19']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ntaylor/Desktop/St Thomas More Log in/File Read Test.py", line 14, in <module>
if row[0] == ("1"):
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

i am of the belief this problem is not a duplicate because the answers given by people in the "duplicate" problem do not fit or fix mine.

any help would be useful, Thanks.

Comment: you should show the csv file, most probably you have empty lines in your csv

Comment: btw, `row[0] == ("1" or "2")` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: if this is a duplicate can someone please show me the duplicate and i'll delete this one.

Comment: but on the first iteration of the for loop it does what i want it to then on the second (or the end of the first) it displays the error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13046897/645956

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Are you sure your csv file and python script match what you've posted exactly?

Comment: It is a space in my CSV file which doesn't show up within notepad,

Comment: how can i remove a newline from csv as soon as it's been writen? when i write from python to the csv file at adds a newline, then my code appends after that newline so there is a space inbetween the 2 entries. :(

Comment: How are you writing to the csv file?