# Stuck: Can't work out the error - index error python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is part of my code (the part that is raising the issues):

```
with open('list.txt') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",") 
    GTINs = []
    products = []
    prices = [] 
    for row in readCSV: 
        GTIN = int(row[0])
        product = row[1]
        price = float(row[2])

        GTINs.append(GTIN) 
        products.append(product)
        prices.append(price)
```

On this line:

```
GTIN = int(row[0])
```

I keep getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range", I have no idea how to fix it. Here is the information I am trying to extract (.txt file):

```
69696961,Milk,1.29
55555555,Bread,0.49
45632549,Milkshake,1.99
```

The error occurred when I made an alteration to the the program (took away two lines).

Any help would be well appreciated as I am well and truly stuck.

Comment: One of the rows in your CSV is empty.

Comment: many csv writers write files in which the last line is empty but exists (second to last contains a newline character). That means the EOF is not reached and there is a blank line at the end as @DanielRoseman says. under the for loop you can add an `if row.rstrip():` before doing the appending

Comment: And a quick fix is to put `if not row: continue` at the top of your `for`...

Comment: Thanks, I feel like such an idiot now. But, thanks again, I never would have noticed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python CSV - list index out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039392/python-csv-list-index-out-of-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove empty lines from the list.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an incorrect or black line in your csv. You can handle the index error with a try-except expression.

```
try:
    GTIN = int(row[0])
    product = row[1]
    price = float(row[2])

    GTINs.append(GTIN) 
    products.append(product)
    prices.append(price)
except IndexError:
    # do something (like "pass" if you don't want that lines)
```

But if you are going to extract the columns you can use `itertools.zip_longest()`

```
from itertools import zip_longest
with open('list.txt') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
    GTIN, product, price = zip_longest(*readCSV, fillvalue="")
```

Note: You can use anything else instead of an empty string for missed values. Or if you don't pass it to the function it will use the default value which is `None`.

As mentioned in comment if you want the items in their real type you can use following approach which is using a generator expression:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
with open('list.txt') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
    rows = ((int(a), b, float(c)) for a, b, c in csv.reader(csvfile))
    GTIN, product, price = zip_longest(*rows, fillvalue="")
```

Comment: @NinjaPuppy What is that?

Comment: @NinjaPuppy Indeed and the `izip()` should be `zip_longest()` :).

Comment: Because of the type conversions, you might want to do: `rows = ((int(a), b, float(c)) for a, b, c in csv.reader(csvfile))` - then `zip_longest(*rows...)` instead

Comment: @NinjaPuppy Yeah it'd be the best way for converting the types, but it depends on what OP wants to do with the result. Anyway I'll update the answer with this proposition too.

Answer (score 0):

What i see here is a txt file not CSV. Here is an easy solution :

```
GTINs = []
products = []
prices = []
with open('stack.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        sentence = line.split(',')
        GTINs.append(sentence[0])
        products.append(sentence[1])
        prices.append(sentence[2])
print(GTINs)
print(products)
print(prices)
```

The output is :
    ['69696961', '55555555', '45632549']
    ['Milk', 'Bread', 'Milkshake']
    ['1.29\n', '0.49\n', '1.99']